# Images on a website look extremely stretched when viewed from a mobile browser

Tags: html, css

I have [this home page of a website](http://www.problemio.com) and when viewed on the web, it appears ok, but when I visit that site from my Android phone's browser, the images look very stretched.

Here is how the HTML looks like:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 255px;">
        <p><h3>Marketing</h3></p>
        <div style="float: left; width: 120px;">
            <p><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/marketing-advertising-articles/id587238156?ls=1&mt=8">
            <img src="http://www.problemio.com/img/app-store-icon.png" style="border: none; height: 99%; width: 99%;" alt="iPhone and iPad Marketing App" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; width: 120px;">
            <p><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marketingpremium">
            <img src="http://problemio.com/img/google-play-icon.png" style="border: none; height: 99%; width: 99%;" alt="Android Marketing App"  /></a></p>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

And the two images appear very stretched when viewing in an Android browser. Would anyone know how to stop that from happening or what is the root cause?

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed. To avoid it, you should create a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and paste the code in the question. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Juhana got it thanks, I'll rephrase the question. Give me a second :)

Comment: What is the resloution of the device you are using, and what is the resolution of the images in question?

Comment: @prodigitalson :) I am not sure what the answer to both your questions is actually :)

Comment: Genadinik man, your problem is not happening on Android on chrome, so i guess is something shepecific for android browser, look for "at" media css codes , that will set height or min heigth for your images, in the code of your page i found this, @media only screen and  and its a lot of code inserted ina <style> tag, its better to insert that code in a order way in a different sheet, this way, this kind of problems can be really easy fixed... But the way you do have it right now, i cant read a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you face the problem every other website on the planet has.
You need to make sure your website template is responsive in order to be fairly sure it shows somewhat properly on smartphones etc.
You can most likely code this yourself, if you are strong in coding, but I am not the guy to tell you how it is done - I just use (responsive) website templates for my sites to get over the issue.